# not able to run all sites automation in loop one by one in selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver

It's not running sites one by one in loop, if site 1 runs then ( sms ) should count 1, and when site 2 runs then ( sms ) should count 2 but when the loop starts, both sites runs once then ( sms ) counts 1.

I want to make it `site 1 = ( sms ) count 1` , `site 2 = ( sms ) count 2`.

If `amount = 50`, then the loop should run 50 times sites 1 by 1 till 50. 
If site 1 runs so `sms = 1` should be like this

```
mobile_number = '9199999999'
amount = 10
for sms in range(1,amount):
    print(sms)

    browser.get('https://www.site.in/') #this is site 1
    time.sleep(2)        
    login = browser.find_element_by_class_name('m-0').click()
    time.sleep(1)
    number = browser.find_element_by_class_name('floating-input').send_keys(mobile_number)         
    button = browser.find_element_by_class_name('decabutton').click()      
    time.sleep(2)

    browser.get('https://www.site.in/customer/account/create/')  #this is site 2
    time.sleep(2)
    number = browser.find_element_by_class_name('mobnumber').send_keys(mobile_number)
    time.sleep(1)         
    otp = browser.find_element_by_class_name('regi-sendotp').click()      
    time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the iteration

```
def make_incrementers():
    amount = 10
    result = []

    for i in range(amount):
        def incrementer(x):
            return x + i
        result.append(incrementer)
    return result
```

Comment: Will you please give me some more examples, THANK YOU.

Comment: This website has all examples 
https://treyhunner.com/2016/04/how-to-loop-with-indexes-in-python/

Comment: its not working :/ i want to make it like, site 1 = count 1 , site 2 = count 2 in loop